# AAD Increase quota for O365 group creation

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create groups using service accounts through microsoft Graph API. There is a limit of 250 groups per non admin user. What is the process to increase this limit for a specific user in AAD tenant.
And what is the max limit it can be increased ?
Currently getting below error while trying to create more than 250 groups:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-admin user can create no more than 250 Azure AD resources(Of course this includes groups).

[image]

**Update:**

Currently, permissions for **Application** registrations are supported in custom roles. More permissions are coming soon.

Now the only way to create more than 250 groups is using admin user.

We can not use the custom role to archive this before the group permissions are released.